# Adobe AIR IOS NSZombieEnabled

Tags: ios, debugging, memory, air, nszombieenabled

I am trying to resolve a memory issue with my adobe air ios app and am having quite a bit of trouble.  I have read in forums etc that the best way to try to find memory issues in ios is to set NSZombieEnabled.

I was wondering if there is any way to set this flag for adobe air ios apps.  I doubt it but thought I would ask.

Thanks

Comment: What is the memory issue you're having?  Zombies are good for detecting access to objects that have been deleted.  Is that what you suspect is happening?

Comment: That is indeed what I think is happening, at least that is what I gathered from reading about the error i am seeing in the ios crashlog (EXC_BAD_ACCESS or EXC_CRASH errors)